# Exception AttributeError: "type object 'instance' has no attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7, class

im getting this exception in Python,

```
Exception AttributeError: "type object 'instance' has no attribute 'jumlah_ada'" in <bound method kucing.__del__ of <__main__.kucing instance at 0x7fe39d827e18>> ignored
```

when i run syntax :

```
class kucing:
        jumlah_ada = 0
        def __init__(self, tipe):
            self.tipe = tipe
            kucing.jumlah_ada +=1
        def __del__(self):
            kucing.jumlah_ada -=1
        def data_kucing(self):
            print "Tipe : ",self.tipe
            print "Jumlah kucing : ",kucing.jumlah_ada

    kucing1 = kucing("Anggora")
    kucing2 = kucing("Persia")
    kucing3 = kucing("Himalayan")


    print "jumlah kucing : ",kucing.jumlah_ada

    kucing1.data_kucing()   
    del kucing2
    print "jumlah kucing : ",kucing.jumlah_ada
```

I've tried to fix it but I still cannot.

Are there any ideas regarding the issue?

Comment: Can you please fix your indentation?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the indentation is not an actual issue, the real issue in your code is that, when the interpreter is exiting, it garbage collects all the objects that it had allocated (that no longer have a reference).

In Python, classes are also objects, hence the classes also get garbage collected. In this case, the class `kucing` gets garbage collected before its instances get garbage collected.

Hence, when the instance gets garbage collected, its `__del__` is called, which tries to access - `kucing.jumlah_ada` - but that is not accessible, and hence causes the `NoneType AttributeError` . A simple way to workaround this would be to change the `__del__()` method to -

```
def __del__(self):
    if kucing:
        kucing.jumlah_ada -=1
```